# What are the best authoritative articles on mantra shashtra online?

Tags: mantras

It will be nice to have list of authoritative practical mantra shashtra n practice article links online which will help all.

Answer (score 2):

I have compiled a short list of articles and a books related to your enquiry about the reference material about Mantra Shastra Online. Some  material is from well known organisation called All World Gayatri Pariwar and well known author Pandit Shriram Sharma Acharya.

---

- Here is the PDF BOOk  - [**THE ETERNITY OF SOUND AND SCIENCE OF MANTRA**](http://literature.awgp.org/var/node/1542/eternity_of_sound_and_the_science_of_mantras.pdf) – BY PANDIT SHRIRAM SHARMA ACHARYA.

[image]

---

- Here are two   brief articles on  - [**Chanting of Mantra**](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/yagy/scientific_aspects_of_yagy/chanting_of_mantr) and [**Science of Mantra**](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/scientific_spiritulality/science_of_mantra)  or Mantra Vigyan

---

- Here is a PDF [**Mantra Yoga**](https://www.himalayanacademy.com/media/books/mantra-yoga_ei/mantra-yoga_ei.pdf) by Himalayanacademy.com - The topic of  science of mantra is  discussed in this  book.

[image]